# Поиск в строке динамического слова - числа

Tags: c++, строки, visual-c++

Есть строка: `string a = "<rand()|1|3|2>"`.

Нужно найти это `rand()` число если до числа идёт `<`, а сразу после `|`.

Как это сделать?

Comment: — Кто на ком стоял? — крикнул Филипп Филиппович, — потрудитесь излагать ваши мысли яснее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string a = "<" + to_string(rand()) + "|1|3|2>";
int first = a.find_first_of("|");
string NeW = a.substr(1, first - 1);
```

Comment: А если число двузначное?

Comment: оно и так двухзначное